# How to rerun a carousel (materialize-css) that has been echoed from database.

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, carousel

I'm trying to save & retrieve an html div with a carousel inside of it, but when I try to store the insides of it (using JavaScript .html() function), to the database this is what get stored...

```html
<div id="panel1">
  <div id="div1" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    <div id="div1_resize" class="div1 carousel carousel-slider initialized" data-namespace="DIVdiv1_resizediv1carouselcarousel-slider0" style="height: 100px; display: none;">
      <a class="carousel-item active" style="z-index: 0; opacity: 1; display: block; transform: translateX(0px) translateX(0px) translateX(0px) translateZ(0px);">
        <div style="background: url(http://172.20.1.23/dmb/public/img/picture1.jpg); background-size: 100% 100%;" class="slider-size2">
        </div>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-item" style="transform: translateX(0px) translateX(-100px) translateZ(0px); z-index: -1; opacity: 1; display: block;">
        <div style="background: url(http://172.20.1.23/dmb/public/img/picture2.jpg); background-size: 100% 100%;" class="slider-size2">
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="div1_resize" class="div1 carousel carousel-slider initialized" data-namespace="DIVdiv1_resizediv1carouselcarousel-sliderinitialized1" style="height: 100px; display: none;">
      <a class="carousel-item" style="z-index: -1; opacity: 1; display: block; transform: translateX(0px) translateX(-100px) translateZ(0px);">
        <div style="background: url(http://172.20.1.23/dmb/public/img/picture1.jpg); background-size: 100% 100%;" class="slider-size2">
        </div>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-item active" style="transform: translateX(0px) translateX(0px) translateX(0px) translateZ(0px); z-index: 0; opacity: 1; display: block;">
        <div style="background: url(http://172.20.1.23/dmb/public/img/picture2.jpg); background-size: 100% 100%;" class="slider-size2">
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="div1_resize" class="div1 carousel carousel-slider initialized" data-namespace="DIVdiv1_resizediv1carouselcarousel-sliderinitialized2" style="height: 400px;">
      <a class="carousel-item active" style="z-index: 0; opacity: 1; display: block; transform: translateX(0px) translateX(0px) translateX(0px) translateZ(0px);">
        <div style="background: url(http://172.20.1.23/dmb/public/img/picture1.jpg); background-size: 100% 100%;" class="slider-size2">
        </div>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-item" style="transform: translateX(0px) translateX(-103.344px) translateZ(0px); z-index: -1; opacity: 1; display: block;">
        <div style="background: url(http://172.20.1.23/dmb/public/img/picture2.jpg); background-size: 100% 100%;" class="slider-size2">
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I try to echo it, it only displays the first image and not as carousel even though it is echoed as a carousel class

```html
<?php
echo htmlspecialchars_decode($temp_row->html);
?>
```

Is there a way to rerun the carousel after it has been echoed?